# i tried implementing "srmklive/paypal": "~1.0", into my laravel project locally, while testing the implementation, i got an error below

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

> Undefined index: secret
> lluminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> C:\wamp64\www\chefruntown\vendor\srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalRequest.php:329

```
private function setApiProviderConfiguration($credentials){
    // Setting PayPal API Credentials

    collect($credentials[$this->mode])->map(function ($value, $key) {

        $this->config[$key] = $value;

    });


    // Setup PayPal API Signature value to use.

    $this->config['signature'] = empty($this->config['certificate']) ?

    $this->config['secret'] : $this->config['certificate'];

    $this->paymentAction = $credentials['payment_action'];

    $this->locale = $credentials['locale'];

    $this->certificate = $this->config['certificate'];

    $this->validateSSL = $credentials['validate_ssl'];

    $this->setApiProvider($credentials);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code which set the paypal credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the paypal.php file found in my config folder with this

```
<?php
/**
 * PayPal Setting & API Credentials
 * Created by Raza Mehdi <srmk@outlook.com>.
 */

return [
    'mode'    => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'), // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => 'APP-80W284485P519543T', // Used for testing Adaptive Payments API in sandbox mode
    ],
    'live' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => '', // Used for Adaptive Payments API
    ],

    'payment_action' => 'Sale', // Can only be 'Sale', 'Authorization' or 'Order'
    'currency'       => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY', 'USD'),
    'billing_type'   => 'MerchantInitiatedBilling',
    'notify_url'     => '', // Change this accordingly for your application.
    'locale'         => '', // force gateway language  i.e. it_IT, es_ES, en_US ... (for express checkout only)
    'validate_ssl'   => true, // Validate SSL when creating api client.
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to match the `.env` variables and `config/paypa.php` variables.

```
PAYPAL_MODE=sandbox
PAYPAL_CURRENCY=USD
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME=username
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD=password
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET=secret-key-or-signature
```

You can retrieve these information by navigating to `paypal sandbox dashboard > leftnav > accounts > sandbox > list of account > view/edit account (action drop down) > API Credentials tab`.

and your config/paypal.php should have the same variables passed.

```
return [
    'mode'    => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'), // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
        // 'client_id'         => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID', ''),
        // 'client_secret'     => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
        // 'app_id'            => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
    ],
    'live' => [
        // 'client_id'         => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID', ''),
        // 'client_secret'     => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_SECRET', ''),
        // 'app_id'            => '',
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => '',
    ],

    'payment_action' => env('PAYPAL_PAYMENT_ACTION', 'Sale'), // Can only be 'Sale', 'Authorization' or 'Order'
    'currency'       => env('PAYPAL_CURRENCY', 'USD'),
    'notify_url'     => env('PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL', ''), // Change this accordingly for your application.
    'locale'         => env('PAYPAL_LOCALE', 'en_US'), // force gateway language  i.e. it_IT, es_ES, en_US ... (for express checkout only)
    'validate_ssl'   => env('PAYPAL_VALIDATE_SSL', true), // Validate SSL when creating api client.
];
```

Note the sandbox and live array, I have commented the default array items with new one.